# Install Windows to partition from a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, macos, partitioning, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am seeking workarounds to installing windows on an SSD partitioned (sharing with macOS) as the normal routes both are unfortunately unsuccessful on my end: boot camp install results in an autounattend.xml error with no resolve found online and setting it up traditionally simply results in a black screen after booting to a windows logo.

so, I figured this might be the way: is it possible to run a virtual machine, be it through VMware, parallels, VirtualBox, etc., and utilize it to install windows to a partition on a disk rather than into a virtual disk (ie, the VM)? I assume at some point during the installation, I would have to reboot into the half-installed windows partition, but as long as I can get to that step, it should be fine.

Search results relating to this are clouded by tutorials on how to install windows to a VM, etc

Comment: Parallels will allow you to run a Boot Camp install as a VM, but I know of nothing that will do the opposite. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414908/cant-find-autounattend-xml

Comment: Don't get your hopes too high. It sounds from your description that the first installation phase was successful without a VM. With your proposed VM approach you'll get the same result, except you'll have to put bootloader on ESP manually.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a VM that uses a partition as a raw disk.
In this way, any installation run inside the VM will be done directly
to a physical disk.

Both VMware and Parallels support raw disks / raw devices.

You will find more information in the documentation of your
virtual machine product.